# MySQL Order By Not Working With Column

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have a query below that is ordering by `'ProgramName'` which uses `lp.name` to sort.  The top value is `'Science - IN'` followed by `'Science - FL'`, but shouldn't `'Science - FL'` be above the other?  Do I need to do something special?

```
SELECT 
    lp.name AS 'program_name'
FROM customer_order co
JOIN customer c on co.customer_id = c.id
JOIN license_program lp ON co.license_program_id = lp.id
ORDER BY 
    CASE lower(sort_direction) WHEN 'asc' THEN
        CASE lower(sort_order)
            WHEN 'programname' THEN lower(lp.name)
            ELSE (entry_date)
        END
    END ASC,
    CASE lower(sort_direction) WHEN 'desc' THEN
        CASE lower(sort_order)
            WHEN 'programname' THEN lower(lp.name)
            ELSE (entry_date)
        END
    END DESC
LIMIT start_page, page_size;
```

Comment: Are you sure that your `sort_direction` is 'asc' and your `sort_order` is 'programname' ?

Comment: You can't dynamically change the sort order (like you're trying to do). And most of your SQL is irrelevant to the question - please edit it down to the base minimum that demonstrates the problem. See [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: The parameters are correct, and this has worked for every search I have done except for this instance.  I think the spaces have something to do with it, but Im not totally sure.

Answer (score 0):

As Bohemian said, you can't dynamically sort like this. The it's currently written, you're basically telling the DB to order ascending first then add a secondary descending sort. You need to code the dynamic sorting logic into the query or table and reference that in the order by.

Comment: This has worked for every search I have done in this application, except for this instance, so I can't say it doesn't work correctly.

Comment: What are the vales sort_direction and entry_data being passed?

Comment: CALL test(1,20,'programname','desc',null,null,null,null,null,'^');

Comment: Why are you expecting the sort to be ascending when you're passing 'desc' into the order by?

Comment: That's just sample code I was testing with.  Pretend its 'ASC'

Comment: This is a long shot, but try replacing `else entry_date` with `else '1'` in the asc case statement.